# Error autowiring an interface class in Spring

Tags: java, spring

My code has this set up:

```
public class myResource() {
   @Autowired
   ImyHandler myHandler;

   ....
}
```

The next layer up contains my handler classes. I have two sets of classes, one is an interface class, and the other is the regular class, like:

```
public interface myHandler() {
      public myObject modifyFunction();
}
```

and then my regular class looks like:

```
public class myHandler() {
     ....
}
```

However, when I build my project, I get this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'myResource': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ImyHandler
```

In my `context-web.xml` file, I declared:

```
<bean id="myHandler" class="myHandler" />
```

I'm not sure why I am getting this error, as I explicitly stated that the interface class is in my context. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Comment: Where is your class that implements the interface? Did you forget to make class `myHandler` implement interface `ImyHandler`? `public class myHandler implements ImyHandler`

Comment: `public class myHandler() {}` does not compile.

Comment: every single line of code you posted here is false ... be it in terms of java, spring or whatever ... you tried to compile anything ?

Comment: @Pras yes, it compiles, this is all psuedo code, I know it won't compile.  I just needed to add "implements ImyHandler" in the "myHandler" method declaration.

Comment: You don't even have an interface called IMyHandler

Comment: @user3334871 you should clean up your "speudo code" ... as i told you, every single line you posted as an error, how do you want us to help you ?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the package of the class in the bean that you want to create.